# Add element to pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a pointer array of a custom `Vector` typedef (just 3 floats). I'm writing a Wavefront object loader and I want to be able to add to an array of these vectors whenever a vertex row in the file is encountered. My problem at the moment is allocating memory for the new vector.

#### Vector

```
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}
Vector;
```

#### Parsing the line and saving in memory

```
Vector *verticies;

Vector tmp;
verticies = new Vector;

long endPtr = sizeof(verticies);

sscanf(line, "v %f %f %f", &verticies[endPtr].x, &verticies[endPtr].y, &verticies[endPtr].z);

return;
```

There are eight vertices in the `.obj` file and the output of `sizeof(verticies)` shows 8 all the time. The problem with the code above is that the new vertex is given to the last element in `*verticies`, so my question is; ** how do I add elements to the end of a pointer array dynamically?**

Comment: Hi, are you sure the C++ tag is appropriate here? The only C++ thing I can see is `operator new`. Everything else is pure C.

Comment: Then yes, it is. This is also wrapped in a class.

Comment: Wrapping something in a class doesn't make it C++, it makes it C with classes. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating space for exactly one `Vector` struct.

`sizeof(vertices)` will be the size of a pointer on your machine and is absolutely meaningless here.

```
sscanf(line, "v %f %f %f", &(verticies->x), &(verticies->y), &(verticies->z));
```

is going to do what you need. But this only enabling you to read in a single `Vector`.
You either need to allocate enough space (as many vectors as you have lines) and use a `for` loop to match the line with the offset in the array.

But you really should be using `std::vector` and a `std::ofstream`.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the correct answer, but I've decided to move to `std::vector` in lue of yours and others advice. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(verticies);
```

always gives 8, because it is a pointer, size of pointer on your environment is 8.

It does not mean you have 8 vertices.

If you want array of Vector of 8 items, you need to do:

```
Vector verticies[8];
```

If you do not know how many `Vector` items you need to use at compile time you should use,
`std::vctor`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) for this. (Or some other standard container.)

Nothing in your code contains an array of pointers. All you have is a pointer to a single `Vector` item that you created with `new Vector`.

`sizeof(vertices)` will give you the size of `vertices` which is a `Vector*`. So `sizeof(vertices)` will always return whatever the size of a pointer is on your platform.

Comment: If OP already knows the size of number of elements at compile time, s/he need not use `std::vector` at all, a simple array would suffice.

Comment: "I want to be able to add to an array of these vectors whenever a vertex row in the file is encountered" - I don't think s/he does

Comment: He doesn't :-) I wrote a loader before that iterated through the file once to count the number of verticies, faces, etc, allocated the correct amount of memory and then went through it again loading the data into RAM. Less than ideal, which is why I asked my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector *verticies;
verticies = new Vector;
```

First of all, `verticies` is not an array of pointers of type `Vector`. It's just a pointer to  `Vector`. So, when ever you creating a instance, `vecticies` is pointing to it. Leaving the last instance it was pointing to behind causing memory leak. If you need array of pointers, then it would be -

```
Vector *verticies[constant];
```

Since you tagged C++, `std::vector` is apt for your program.

```
std::vector <Vector> verticies ;
```

Now, do a push_back operation for each instance you create.